# ASP.NET Link Button change on jQuery slider

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have two jQuery sliders in my page - A user will be a width and height and then click a button which should go to a New Url with them value as querystring parameters.

So I have two asp HiddenFields on my page that I set too the value of the slider - that seems to be working ok.

```
<asp:linkbutton ID="bmiLink" class="action-button" Text="Click for BMI" ToolTip="View your BMI" runat="server" OnClick="btnBMI_Click" />
```

I then have the following C# in my Code Behind:

```
    protected void btnBMI_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get Values from Hidden Fields
        string weight = weight .Value;
        string height= height.Value;

        bmiLink.PostBackUrl = string.Format("/BMIPage?{0}={1}&{2}={3}", QueryStringConstants.Weight, weight , QueryStringConstants.Height, height);
    }
```

When I first load the page the slider values are both zero and if I hover over the button - the link is appearing as -

```
javascript: __doPostBack('ct100$ct100$bodyContent$formContent$bmiLink',")
```

If I change the slider value to say weight 150 and height 180 I want the button link to get updated.  What is the best way to achieve this?

The way it is working now - I have to click the button which gets the values and then posts back to the page and resets the sliders to 0 but updates the link on the button to include the correct query parameters.  So is there a way I can easily dynamically set the link on the button driven by the values that the sliders are set too?

Comment: Why not change the link at the client side? Just a few query-statements will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could instead consider doing everything on the client, so in your button do:

```
<asp:LinkButton .. OnClientClick="postback(this, event);" />

function postback(sender, e) {
   //you may have to use e.stopPropagation() and e.preventDefault() to prevent the default postback operation

   var val = /* jquery expression to get the value */
   __doPostBack("<%= Button.UniqueID %>", val);
}
```

And then it will grab the value from the client.  You can then change it to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks - used this idea - just changed and did a document.location.href = val; rather than __doPostBack

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line in the btnBMI_Click event handler to:

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://domain.com/BMIPage?{0}={1}&{2}={3}", QueryStringConstants.Weight, weight , QueryStringConstants.Height, height));
```